# Case Timer - continue counter on reactivation of case page

Tags: lightning, event

I try to set up our own Case Timer. This is the code so far:

Controller:

```
 init : function(component, event, helper) {

        var startTime = null;
        var startTime_String = null;
        var time = 0;
        var diff;
        var minutes;
        var seconds;
        var timer;

        startTime = Date.now();
        startTime_String = Date(startTime).toString();
        component.set("v.startTime" , startTime_String);

        var timer = setInterval(
            $A.getCallback(function() {
                helper.timer(component, event, helper, startTime, time, diff, minutes, seconds)
            }), 1000);

        window.onblur = function() { hasFocus = false; 
            clearInterval(timer);                 
        };


}
```

Helper:

```
timer : function(component, event, helper, startTime, time, diff, minutes, seconds) {
        diff = (Date.now() - startTime)/1000;

        minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
        seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        time = minutes + ":" + seconds;
        component.set("v.time" , time);     
}
```

The counter works fine. However, when I open another tab in the browser, it gets interrupted. This behaviour is ok. But when I navigate back to the Case page, I want it to continue.

Now I do not know how to embed an event that gets fired when the user navigates back to the Case browser tab. Any suggestions on this? Thanks!

Comment: You just need to add an onfocus handler as well. Have you tried that?

Comment: You are right, window.onfocus, window.onbeforeunload and window.onblur all function together with the timer within the init function <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>